# Cant delete file access denied?

Tags: c#, cmd

Spent days trying to get this working. I watched video [C# Auto Updater](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=325Uxy5nVI0) 1-10 step by step.
Almost completed except the very last part. When running the code I had to make command visible to see what the error was the error I'm getting is at the DEl command **Access denied**. In Part the code downloads a XML file from my website determine if update is available if so it downloads the file to the Temp dir Shuts down the app, Deletes the current file moves the temp file and restarts the app.  Is there a better way or can this code be changed to accomplish this. I tried running as admin still errors out.

```
 private void UpdateApplication(string tempFilePath, string currentPath, string newPath)
    {
                    //Alow program to quit 4 sec delay & Delete file quietly   &  allow a 2 sec delay before moving & /Y overwites    & start new file
        string argument = "/C Choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 4 & Del /F /Q \"{0}\" & Choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 2 & Move /Y \"{1}\" \"{2}\" & Start \"\" /D \"{3}\" \"{4}";

        // only showed window to troubleshoot Cant Delete file access denied
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.Arguments = string.Format(argument, currentPath, tempFilePath, newPath, Path.GetDirectoryName(newPath), Path.GetFileName(newPath));
        info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        Process.Start(info);
    }

//Try to download file it is proper bytes
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
        using (downloader)
        {
            try
            {
                string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\TestApp1.exe";
                downloader.DownloadFile("https://sourcecodedepot.com/update/TestApp1.exe", appPath);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ae)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", ae.GetType(), ae.Message);
            }
            catch (WebException webEx)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", webEx.GetType(), webEx.Message);
                Debug.WriteLine("Destination not found!");
            }
            catch (NotSupportedException supportEx)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", supportEx.GetType(), supportEx.Message);
                Debug.WriteLine(supportEx.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception allExp)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", allExp.GetType(), allExp.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Access Denied" likely means your app is still running. Where is your app being shutdown? How is your command string waiting on that?

Comment: you can't delete, but you can always rename

Comment: According to tutorial /C Choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 4  means it start a close and waits 4 seconds to delete file. As per AndersK statement renaming may be an option will have to look at that.

Comment: You have unmatched quotes in your argument string: ```"/C Choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 4 & Del /F /Q \"{0}\" & Choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 2 & Move /Y \"{1}\" \"{2}\" & Start \"\" /D \"{3}\" \"{4}\"";```. But, this is more technically correct: ```"/D /C \"Choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 4 & Del /A /F /Q \"{0}\" & Choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 2 & Move /Y \"{1}\" \"{2}\" & Start \"\" /D \"{3}\" \"{4}\"\"";```.

Comment: Awesome will try that and let you know. I did give up and went with AutoUpdater.net. But I still will try to solve the issue. Thanks

Comment: It worked Thanks Compo. Probably a different issue but the file after moving is 0 bytes.

Comment: Added webclient code above to see if it was on my server side. The file did download properly 13 bytes so i assume its something in the command prompt. any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Compo I did figure this out I have uploaded the code to git hub just in case anyone elese want to create their own AppUpdater.net.
https://github.com/DwainSnickles/SharpUpdate
Here is some of the code changes I made to eliminate 0 bytes download:

```
private void UpdateApplication(string tempFilePath, string currentPath, string newPath)
    {
        //Alow program to quit 4 sec delay & Delete file quietly   &  allow a 2 sec delay before moving & /Y overwites    & start new file
        string argument = "/D /C \"Choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 4 & Del /A /F /Q \"{0}\" & Choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 2 & Move /Y \"{1}\" \"{2}\" & Start \"\" /D \"{3}\" \"{4}\"\"";

        // only showed window to troubleshoot Cant Delete file access denied
        //in real app you should hide the cmd window
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.Arguments = string.Format(argument, currentPath, tempFilePath, newPath, Path.GetDirectoryName(newPath), Path.GetFileName(newPath));
        info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        Process.Start(info);
    }

 private void DownloadUpdate(SharpUpdateXml update)
    {
        //Form f = new Form1(update.Uri, update.MD5, this.applicationInfo.ApplicationIcon);
        //f.ShowDialog();
        SharpUpdateDownloadForm form = new SharpUpdateDownloadForm(update.Uri, update.MD5, this.applicationInfo.ApplicationIcon);
        DialogResult result = form.ShowDialog(this.applicationInfo.Context);
        string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\TestApp1.exe";

        if (result == DialogResult.OK || result == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            // Download file using webclient and add the file to bin folder
            WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
            
            using (downloader)
            {
                try
                {
                    downloader.DownloadFile("https://sourcecodedepot.com/update/TestApp1.exe", appPath);
                }
                catch (ArgumentException ae)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", ae.GetType(), ae.Message);
                }
                catch (WebException webEx)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", webEx.GetType(), webEx.Message);
                    Debug.WriteLine("Destination not found!");
                }
                catch (NotSupportedException supportEx)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", supportEx.GetType(), supportEx.Message);
                    Debug.WriteLine(supportEx.Message);
                }
                catch (Exception allExp)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", allExp.GetType(), allExp.Message);
                }
            }

            string currentPath = this.applicationInfo.ApplicationAssembly.Location;
            string newPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(currentPath) + "\\" + update.Filename;

            UpdateApplication(appPath, currentPath, newPath);

            Application.Exit();
        }
        else if (result == DialogResult.Abort)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The update download was cancellled.\nThis Program has not been updated", "Updated Cancelled", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was problem trying to download update.\nUpload download error", "Updated Cancelled", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
```